# Trim is not returning a string without the characters I want to remove

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to remove 2 chars from a string: '-', '.'

According to microsoft documentation, if I provide a array of characters as a parameter to trim, it should remove then and return a new string.

Here is the code I trying:

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '-', '.'};
string newCPF = usuario.Cpf.Trim(charsToTrim);
usuario.Cpf = newCPF;
_context.Add(usuario);
```

The string is something like this 000.000.000-00, but trim is not removing the . and -

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Trim` only trims from the ends, not inside the string. Use `String.Replace` or some other means.

Answer (score 1):

Trim only removes the specified characters from the start and the end of the string.

You could just use `String.Replace` to remove those characters:

```
string newCPF = usuario.Cpf.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "");
```

Comment: Thanks, it make senses. I found it in the documentation after reading your comment:
Removes white spaces or characters specified in an array of characters from the beginning and end of a string.